# PC shows this error while booting up

Tags: boot, hp, 18.10

The window does boot up, but it shows the following errors at bootup screen.

```
pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: PCIe Bus Error: severity=uncorrected (Non-Fatal), type = transaction Layer, (Completer ID)
pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: device [8086:9d15] error status/mask=00008000/00010000
pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:   [15] completer abort         (First)
pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: TLP Header: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

Is this an error? Do I have to do anything, and/or what is the impact?

Updated: Reports only for Dec-17 are as under:

```
Dec 17 11:47:10 engineer-HP-ProBook-450-G5 kernel: [    3.401392] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: OS now controls [PCIeHotplug SHPCHotplug PME AER PCIeCapability LTR]
Dec 17 11:47:10 engineer-HP-ProBook-450-G5 kernel: [    4.410646] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: AER enabled with IRQ 120
Dec 17 11:47:10 engineer-HP-ProBook-450-G5 kernel: [    4.410677] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER enabled with IRQ 121
Dec 17 11:47:10 engineer-HP-ProBook-450-G5 kernel: [    4.410707] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0: AER enabled with IRQ 122
Dec 17 11:47:17 engineer-HP-ProBook-450-G5 kernel: [   34.454681] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: Uncorrected (Non-Fatal) error received: 0000:00:1c.5
Dec 17 11:47:17 engineer-HP-ProBook-450-G5 kernel: [   34.458033] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: Device recovery failed
Dec 17 11:47:20 engineer-HP-ProBook-450-G5 kernel: [   37.834700] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: Uncorrected (Non-Fatal) error received: 0000:00:1c.5
Dec 17 11:47:20 engineer-HP-ProBook-450-G5 kernel: [   37.838915] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: Device recovery failed
Dec 17 11:47:42 engineer-HP-ProBook-450-G5 colord[3693]: Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: laErrMessage ::= { laEntry 101 }
Dec 17 11:47:42 engineer-HP-ProBook-450-G5 colord[3693]: Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: laErrorFlag ::= { laEntry 100 }
```

Output for grep -i "PCIe Bus Error" /var/log/syslog*

```
Dec 17 11:47:17 engineer-HP-ProBook-450-G5 kernel: [   34.454706] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Uncorrected (Non-Fatal), type=Transaction Layer, (Completer ID)
Dec 17 11:47:20 engineer-HP-ProBook-450-G5 kernel: [   37.834711] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Uncorrected (Non-Fatal), type=Transaction Layer, (Completer ID)
Dec 17 17:14:23 engineer-HP-ProBook-450-G5 kernel: [   34.295027] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Uncorrected (Non-Fatal), type=Transaction Layer, (Completer ID)
Dec 17 17:14:26 engineer-HP-ProBook-450-G5 kernel: [   37.456799] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Uncorrected (Non-Fatal), type=Transaction Layer, (Completer ID)
Dec 17 22:35:48 engineer-HP-ProBook-450-G5 kernel: [   32.872801] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Uncorrected (Non-Fatal), type=Transaction Layer, (Completer ID)
Dec 17 22:35:52 engineer-HP-ProBook-450-G5 kernel: [   36.169689] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Uncorrected (Non-Fatal), type=Transaction Layer, (Completer ID)
Dec 17 22:36:03 engineer-HP-ProBook-450-G5 kernel: [   47.950198] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Uncorrected (Non-Fatal), type=Transaction Layer, (Completer ID)
Dec 17 22:36:11 engineer-HP-ProBook-450-G5 kernel: [   55.548353] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Uncorrected (Non-Fatal), type=Transaction Layer, (Completer ID)
```

Comment: It seems to be a 'non-fatal' error. In other words, you can live with it. Is your computer working well enough, or do you think that it is failing or slow?

Comment: You probably have old/incorrect (Nvidia?) video drivers installed.

Comment: @sudodus yes it is getting slow, sometimes hang a bit

Comment: @heynnema how to check it, and install new drivers?

Comment: @heynnema updated the drivers, no effect

Comment: In order to help us help you, please specify: 1. The computer (which hp model?); 2. The graphics chip/card; 3. The amount of RAM; 4. The flavour of Ubuntu (standard Ubuntu or Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Ubuntu Budgie ... Xubuntu).

Comment: I don't have a fix for you yet, but this article sheds some light on the subject... https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/PCI/pcieaer-howto.txt. Do these errors also show up in syslog?

Comment: @sudodus 1: HP-Probook-450GS, 2: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07), 3: 4GB Ram, 4: Ubuntu 18.10 (normal version)

Comment: Lets see if these errors appear (in quantity) in your syslog. Edit your question to show me the `terminal` output of `grep -i aer /var/log/syslog*` or `grep -i "PCIe Bus Error" /var/log/syslog*`. Ping me at @heynnema

Comment: @HamzaSaeed, The hardware specs are powerful enough for all Ubuntu versions and flavours. The computer is new, so it was a good idea to try 18.10, the newest version of Ubuntu. You could even experiment with the developing version [Disco Daily](http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/398/builds) (to be released as 19.04 next April). Newer versions come with newer hardware drivers. On the other hand, the newest version with long time support is best debugged and polished, so it is worthwhile to try Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS. -- I am also awaiting the result of your dialogue with heynnema.

Comment: @heynnema Question updated

Comment: @HamzaSaeed thanks for the update. Always include the complete command that you typed in your updates, so that I can see exactly what you did. I suspect that you forgot the * at the end of the first command. What did the second command give you?

Comment: @heynnema check the update

Comment: @HamzaSaeed  Since syslog doesn't appear to be bombed with AER errors, and if it only appears at boot time, and is non-fatal, I'd say ignore the error for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments...

After checking `/var/log/syslog*` for AER error bombing, and noting that the error only occurs at boot time, and it's non-fatal, you can ignore the error for now.

More info about AER errors, and what they are, can be found at https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/PCI/pcieaer-howto.txt.